# Condition that a family of unitary and antiunitary operators actually consists of unitary operators only

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am currently reading a book on linear operators in quantum mechanics in which the following statement is made in a chapter on propagators.

Let $\mathcal{F} = \{ U(t,s) \: | \: s,t \in \mathbb{R} \}$ be a family of operators in a Hilbertspace $\mathcal{H}$, each of which is either unitary or antiunitary. Furthermore, the following conditions apply to all $r,s,t \in \mathbb{R}$:

1. $U(t,s) U(s,r) = U(t,r)$.
2. The map $(s,t) \mapsto U(s,t)$ is strongly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then all $U(t,s) \in \mathcal{F}$ are unitary.

The following definitions are used: A bounded operator $U : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is called unitary if it is surjective and $(U x , U y) = (x,y)$ holds for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$. $U$ is called antiunitary if it is surjective and $(U x , U y) = (y,x)$ is valid for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$.

The surjectivity of every $U(t,s) \in \mathcal{F}$ is clear, since any unitary or antiunitary operator is surjective. Furthermore we have that $U(t,s)$ is injective, since $|| U x || = || x||$ applies. Therefore $U(t,s)$ is bijective and using item 1 we find its inverse operator to be $U(t,s)^{-1} = U(s,t)$.

To show the condition $(U(s,t) x , U(s,t) y) = (x,y)$ for all $U(s,t) \in \mathcal{F}$ and all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$, I honestly do not have a bright idea. Approximating an arbitrary element $U \in \mathcal{F}$ by a sequence unitary operators $U(t_n, s_n) \in \mathcal{F}$ in the strong operator topology (if such a sequence exists) will not work, since the set of unitary operators is not closed in the set of linear and bounded operators (with respect to SOT).

I am grateful for every hint.
Thanks in advance,
GordonFreeman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a $v\in H$ and for aesthetic purposes let $\|v\|=1$. Consider the map
$$\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R,\qquad (t,s)\mapsto \|iU(t,s)v - U(t,s)iv\|$$
The value at $(t,s)$ is $0$ if $U$ is unitary and $2$ if $U$ is anti-unitary, no other values are taken. Since the map is continuous you have that the pre-images of $0$ (resp $2$) are open and closed.

The only open and closed sub-sets of $\Bbb R^2$ are $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R^2$. Since $U(1,1)=\Bbb 1$ is unitarythe pre-image of $0$ cannot be $\emptyset$, so $U(t,s)$ is unitary for all $(t,s)$.

Comment: Wow, what a simple and elegant solution! Thank you very much! I would never have thought of this ...  But that's the beauty of math; you always learn something new :)